# No emails with 'Sent' folder in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have Outlook 2007 on my Windows 7 PC. For some reason, when I send an email, it does not also appear in the 'Sent' folder. What should I do?

Comment: Well, first you should add a ton of more information about your current setup and problem before we can even begin to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'm having a problem due to the fact that when I send an email the same email doesn't show up in my 'Sent' folder. Isn't that where a carbon copy of one's email is placed? I know there's a way to set it up. If that's still not a ton of info, then what is it you would have to know about the 'current setup'.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following advice from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/ms-outlook-2007-sent-items-disappear-in-sent-item/41134b71-5a79-4415-bf09-dd2c2fb9f386?page=2):

> Click on (highlight) Sent Items. View>Current View>Sent to (my user
>   had Unread Messages in this Folder checked). When I changed to "Sent
>   To" everything appeared.
>
> You may, also, want to check Filters. View>Current View>Customize
>   Current View>Filter (4th one down).

Other potential reasons include: Outlook rules which move away sent items, synchronization to mobile devices, integration of virus protection, Outlook/Exchange chaching problems, ...

Comment: Hi, wrt the 1st sugg'n, the 'Sent To' was already checked. WRT the 2nd .....where is 'Filters View' so I can begin trying it?

Comment: Whoaaaaa.....stop presses. It works!!